# Server 2008 R2 in office with 5 users, Opening another office down the road, same domain?

Tags: windows-server-2008

Hope this is the best place to ask this question!

We currently have a small office with 5 computers and a server 2008 R2. We have just opened another small office literally across the road... sadly out of Wifi range so are looking to connect another 5 PC's in this office, with server, and link it to the same domain potentially over VPN.

However I have no idea if this is the best way to go around this. All users in both offices need to be able to log on to any PC and the file server in our primary office needs to be able to be accessed in our secondary office.

Both offices have a broadband connection and is currently running around 4mb/s down.

Any input would be gratefully appreciated and wither or not this is the best way to go about this?

Cheers in advance,
Chris

Comment: how far is the actual distance between buildings?  Consider using wireless repeaters between them to connect the 2 LANs if you don't want to go s2s vpn.

Comment: Ubiquiti Nanostation M5s could probably pull off ~100Mbps full-duplex through a window even...

Comment: Question: why does each user need to remotely access one another's computers?

Comment: @gravyface I think he means the users can work at any computer in either office and need to be able to sit down at any computer and be able to work/logon to the workstation and access the file server in the main office.

Comment: `literally across the road`, how wide is the road? Try attaching a directional yagi antenna, then you should be good for a few kilometers.

Comment: Hey guys, Site to site should be alright for us. Got VPN set up and have a DC at each site, Just confused now as how to share files between them. MikeAWood suggested DFS-R but I have no idea where to start with this and will this work over a Broadband connection through VPN sufficiently?

Comment: @user181682 I would highly recommend you seek out a professional to at least give you a quote on a point-to-point wireless link if there's a clear line of sight. No recurring costs each month, 10-20 times the speed, no need for DFS, can bridge them right on your LAN.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, definitely use 1 domain for this (preferably with at least one Domain Controller at each site) and use something like a site-to-site VPN to logically stretch the one network across the two sites. Talk to your ISP about what options they have to facilitate connectivity between the two sites. They can probably do MPLS, or a simple site-to-site link for you.

Comment: Hey MDMarra, A domain controller at each site is do-able and site-to-site VPN is what im planning however I have managed to set-up our primary server for routing and remote access to allow VPN however I am stuck as to how to set up our secondary server I have AD installed on it currently and also routing and remote access... Confused as to how to set this up do I run DCPROMO to set up another site at office 2?

Comment: You join the new server to the existing domain, then you run `dcpromo` and select "Add to an existing forest" (or whatever the actual text is).

Comment: Ideally a step by step as to what I need to do on "server2" would be ideal!

Comment: And about VPN to have an "Always on" connection?

Comment: Like I said...a site to site VPN or contact your ISP for their options...

Comment: Got VPN and DC's at each site, just wondering about file sharing now! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Windows 2008 will let you do DFS-R which if setup correctly, you could replicate your files from one location to the other in near-realtime (bandwidth permitting of course).  If you did both as an AD member server, you could easily allow logins at both locations and access to their files would happen between either server.  The other added benefit of this is that if one server goes down, you could set it up to use the other office's server during disaster recovery.

Comment: Hey, sounds IDEAL! How do you set this up?

Comment: You'd still need the VPN like MDMarra mentioned below, but read up on DFS and DFS-R and how it is setup.  It can work well for situations like yours if you have the knowledge to set it up properly.  Doing so is not a simple "do this" answer, so you'll likely need to do more research.

Comment: Read up on it and have managed to get OUR DC1 "Server" as namespace and replica to DC2 "Server(Other Location)" looking great so far and works a treat!! What a fab solution I would never have thought of! Got all files backed up at each location then aswell, cost effective! Just looking to get roaming profiles setup now as the paths are slightly different, Im assuming is just changing it from what is it just now "\\SERVER\ShineUserRoam$\CQuinn" to something like "\\domain.local\centralshare\ShineUserRoam$\CQuinn"?

Comment: Depending on the size of the files, it can take a bit for everything to sync.  But if you can deal with the lag of the replication, it works in some cases.  If you have things like PST files or other large work files, you might have to use a different method for syncing over user folders. But YMMV.